# Gitlab Fingerprint has already been taken, Deploy keys projects deploy key fingerprint has already been taken

Tags: ssh, gitlab, vps, deploy-keys

I want to deploy two projects in the same VPS.i've successfully deployed one project and added Deploy keys to the GitLab repository.but when I try to add the same ssh key to my other repositories Deploy keys it says,

**Fingerprint has already been taken, Deploy keys projects deploy key fingerprint has already been taken**

what happening here? is it not possible to add the same key to two projects?

any advice, please.

Answer (score 16):

answering my own question, maybe this will save someone else time.

actually there is a way to add the same key to multiple projects.the problem was i didn't read the content carefully.

[image]

in here it's clearly say's **You can create a deploy key or add an existing one**

in here it shows your existing keys.

[image]

all you need to do is enable that key to this project

Click on enable button next to your key.

[image]

and it will enable to your project

[image]

that's it.you good to go.good luck